# How can I use html2pdf to render the whole page

Tags: html, css, html2pdf

how to let my html2pdf render the whole page? please see the example image  [Current page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNxS3.png)
[PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHPoz.png)

```
exportToPDF() {
let data = Object.assign({}, this.$refs);
            html2pdf(data.document, {
            margin: 1,
            filename: "invoice.pdf",
            image: { type: "jpeg", quality: 0.98 },
            html2canvas: { dpi: 300, letterRendering: true, },
            jsPDF: { unit: "in", format: "a4", orientation: "l" },
            });            
},
```

Comment: Can you give us a sample code of what you try to render.

Comment: Their might be issue in closing div. Try validating your html code using an online tool for once.

Comment: Hi guys, I found out what was the problem already, its about the pdf sheet format I use 'b4' to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After change a4 format to b4 everything works well, thanks guys.

[image: Solved Image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).